# Relation between order and order status table in admin panel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-6

I'm creating a foreign key relationship between the `orders` and `order_status` tables. When I get a new order from the customer and ship that order, I set that order status to shipped when the order is received to that customer. I set shipped and received status, and then that order will start showing on the orders history page. Am I doing this correctly?

```
class CreateOrdersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->text('customer_name');
            $table->string('customer_email');
            $table->string('customer_contact');
            $table->bigInteger('order_status_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('product_names');
            $table->string('products_quantity');
            $table->text('customer_address');
            $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here's the order_status table:

```
class CreateOrderStatusTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('order_status', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('status')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your exact query here?? how we can help you??

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, an Order could have multiple OrderStatuses.  To facilitate this in Eloquent (not covered here), your `order_status` table needs another column referencing the`orders` table.

Add this to the `order_status` migration:

```php
$table->bigInteger('order_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders');
```

Comment: ok sir i have added these lines, but please tell me that is way is correct way to add order status in  orders, means making seprate table of order status and connecting it to orders table????????????

Comment: I use [this](https://hackernoon.com/eloquent-relationships-cheat-sheet-5155498c209) as my go-to reference for Eloquent, but if you're asking this question, you could benefit from following a tutorial.  i recommend Jeffrey Way's excellent Laracasts series, [Laravel 5.7 From Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018).